# Tomcat LDAP JNDI Realm Exception

Tags: tomcat

I'm having a problem with the way Apache Tomcat behaves when authenticating with the LDAP server.

When I first attempt to login, everything is good. If I leave the connection idle for some time, then just log out (for test purposes) and log back in, it throws the exception mentioned below but does successfully login. Why does this happen?

Note that this doesn't happen if I keep using the app without logging out.

Here is my server configuration

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
Server built:   Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
Server number:  8.0.24.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.18-238.el5
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_67-b01
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Here is the console output that has the exception trace. The first two lines are the output due to me logging out and then the exception is created when I try to log back in (which is eventually successful)

```
2015-08-18 15:47:14.493 DEBUG 28842 --- [io-8180-exec-10] c.c.c.a.c.BaseAceConsoleApplication      : Cleared cookie JSESSIONID, value= 1157DD8C066BBC384E7C2BAD380476A8
2015-08-18 15:47:14.494 DEBUG 28842 --- [io-8180-exec-10] c.c.c.a.c.BaseAceConsoleApplication      : Cleared cookie JSESSIONIDSSO, value= 3800C322B28A40CB74A5CDBC3AAD46C5
18-Aug-2015 15:47:18.780 INFO [http-nio-8180-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate Exception performing authentication. Retrying...
 javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]; remaining name 'DC=companyname,DC=com'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:162)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2740)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2648)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.ensureOpen(LdapCtx.java:2622)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.doSearch(LdapCtx.java:1942)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1847)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1772)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:386)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:339)
    at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUserBySearch(JNDIRealm.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1517)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.getUser(JNDIRealm.java:1465)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1406)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.authenticate(JNDIRealm.java:1264)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.authenticate(CombinedRealm.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate(LockOutRealm.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:245)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:853)
    ... 1 more

2015-08-18 15:47:19.150 DEBUG 28842 --- [nio-8180-exec-1] c.c.c.a.c.s.AceConsoleUserDetailsService : Looking up user azafar200
2015-08-18 15:47:19.154 DEBUG 28842 --- [nio-8180-exec-1] c.c.c.a.c.s.AceConsoleUserDetailsService : Found user azafar200
2015-08-18 15:47:19.155  INFO 28842 --- [nio-8180-exec-1] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Aug 18 15:47:19 UTC 2015, principal=azafar200, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesWebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 10.21.138.140; SessionId: 182B7DDB80CABA34C93DD536871339B4; []}]
```

Comment: Connection reset: you have unreliable servers or network.

Comment: What? The servers that I'm working with are quite reliable. I've a feeling that this is a bug (which is documented in Tomcat 7) coming back in version 8.

Comment: How can this be a Tomat bug if the root cause is a SocketException within JNDI?

Comment: I believe this is more about the JNDIRealm class not handling the exception gracefully? Note that the exception above doesn't stop the code from functioning, it just resets the connection and then attempts the login.

Comment: The socket is reset by the peer, it did close the connection for some reason or the connection was dropped. This isn't something the JNDIRealm can do.